# No route found issues with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a listings page for businesses, each show page has a form. Because of this set up it means that I need 2 different new/create actions. I tried to define that using the following code:

```
<%= form_for @lead, :url => { :action => :leadcreate } do |lead|%>
```

However, this did not work. In my routes file I also have resources called for listings, and as the leads are contained within the listings controller I expected this to cover it but apparently not.

I then get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"leadcreate", :controller=>"listings", :id=>"1"
```

On

```
<%= form_for @lead, :url => { :action => :leadcreate } do |lead|%>
```

Any idea what is the issue here?

Comment: Can you please show your code for your routes file that pertains to this?

Comment: @StephRose listings is the controller which has the leadnew and leadcreate methods

Answer (score 0):

What controller has this `:leadcreate` action? You have to pass the controller's name as a param to `:url` helper

Should be: `<%= form_for @lead, url: {controller: 'controller_name', action: :leadcreate } do |lead|%>`

Another option is to use generated route:
 `<%= form_for @lead,listings_lead_path do |lead|%>` or whatever the path is called when you run `rake routes` in terminal

Comment: listings controller does, I have tried     <%= form_for @lead, :url => {:controller => "listings" :action => :leadcreate } do |lead|%> and received a syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end error

Comment: @JayMcNaught check the updated answer again, the comma is missed between controllr and action

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"leadcreate", :controller=>"listings", :id=>"1"}

Comment: could you please run `rake routes` in terminal, and update the question with its result?

Answer (score 0):

in your routes file you probably want something like this.

```
resources :listings do
   member do
     post :leadcreate
   end
end
```

which would give you `leadcreate_listing_path`  to use in your form.

but if leads are always scoped under a listed you can use a nested resource.

```
resources :listings do
   resources: :leads
end
```

and then create a leads controller to handle them.  There is lots of information on the web on how to do this,  Then you can use the standard restful actions/crud to create them.

Comment: Did your first suggestion, now I'm getting a missing template error? really I just want it to send the form and then re-direct to the same page.

Comment: Missing template listings/leadcreate, application/leadcreate with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Callum/Documents/directory/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"

Comment: Just make sure that your lead create action redirect. If it makes it to the end of the the action without a redirect it will by default try to render a template with the action name